# Массивы и http_build_query

Tags: php, массивы

Есть код:

```
$data = array(
    'other' => array(
        'method' => 'wall.createComment'
    ),
    'static' => array( //Данные, которые не меняются
        'owner_id' => $owner_id,
        'post_id' => $post_id
    ),
    'dynamic' => array( //Данные, которые меняются
        'message' => $comments,
        'access_token' => $tokens
    )
);
```

$comments и $tokens - это массивы (Ключи массива - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 и.т.д)

```
while($i < 20){

    $request = "https://api.vk.com/method/".$data['other']['method']."?".http_build_query($data['static'])."&message=".$message[$i]."&comments=".$comments[$i]."v=5.94";
}
```

Запрос должен быть таким. Вместо "&message=".$message[$i] и "&comments=".$comments[$i] данные должны браться из массива $data['dynamic']. Ключи и количество ключей - неизвестны, они все должны подставляться в ссылку

Comment: `foreach ($comments as $key => $value) {}` не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил.

```
$array = array_keys($data['dynamic']);
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $add .= '&'.$value.'='.$data['dynamic'][$value][$i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$request = 'https://api.vk.com/method/' . http_build_query($data);
```

Comment: Это не то, что мне нужно